# Laravel Chunking Results utility

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

According to Laravel Documentation

> If you need to work with **thousands** of database records, consider
>   using the chunk method. This method **retrieves a small chunk of the
>   results at a time** and feeds each chunk into a Closure for
>   processing. This method is very useful for writing Artisan commands
>   that process thousands of records. For example, let's work with the
>   entire users table in chunks of 100 records at a time:

```
DB::table('users')->orderBy('id')->chunk(100, function ($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        //
    }
});
```

Is it supposed to reduce waiting time ?

I can't see how this feature is helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chunking allows you to break a big query and subsequent processing task into a repeated step.

The most common application of this technique is to avoid hitting memory limits. If you are loading hundreds of thousands of rows from the database and then doing a transformation process on them, that can chew up a lot of memory and could very easily hit limits defined in php.ini.

Depending on the context, you can push the results to screen as soon as each chunk finishes, which means you have reduced wait time for the initial results while overall processing time has likely increased while result notifications would come in one chunk at a time.

Comment: But chunking results and looping through them each time will consume the same amout of memory as fetching all rows at once , right ?

Comment: "Depending on the context, you can push the results to screen as soon as each chunk finishes..", Do you mean broadcast data via sockets to front-end ?? cause i can't see how it is possible with the  return view() statement ?

Comment: It will not use the same amount of memory, no. Once the initial chunk is completed and the second chunk starts, the variables within the process method will be overwritten with the new chunk. You are working with each chunk rather than the entire result set all at once.

Broadcasting data via socket is the best option in a web interface setting for sure. Chunking makes a lot more sense in a command line / artisan setting where incremental output is much more achievable.